# Android java вызов функции из переменной

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как сохранить функцию в переменную, чтобы после была возможность её вызова?

Мне нужно обрабатывать кнопку "назад" в `onBackPressed()`. Хочу при смене `layout` указывать в переменной функцию, которая должна вызываться при нажатии кнопки "назад".

Это кажется самым простым вариантом. Есть другие варианты?

Comment: А почему нельзя просто по нажатию на кнопку назад выбирать определенное действие?

Comment: Это можно сделать, если знать какой layout сейчас активен. Как это узнать? В принципе это решение, но мне больше нравится вариант в вопросе, он позволит чуть больше свободы.

Comment: И все-таки меня не покидает чувство что вы выбрали не лучшее решение. Как и какой именно layout вы меняете?

Comment: Я делаю так:  Активити{ OnMain(){ setContentView(R.layout.main); } OnChat(){ setContentView(R.layout.chat); } } .

Comment: Почему бы не использовать фрагменты? У них и бекстек есть.

Comment: Фрагменты я пока не осилил, поэтому пользуюсь тем, что понимаю.

Answer (score 5):

Подмена `ContentView` в активити - плохая практика и ведет к большому количеству ненужных и порой невероятных костылей и еще более неправильных решений (есть считанное количество случаев , когда это оправдано , но случай в вопросе к ним не относится)

Существует прстое правило : одна активити - один контентвью , его надо сразу запомнить.
Если осилить фрагменты пока не удалось (хотя тут и использование фрагментов тоже сомнительно) , когда требуется другой экран , создавайте новую активити и вызывайте ее , а не подменяйте контентвью

Хотелось бы обратиться к сообществу не поощрять подобную практику, придумывая какие то сложные решения для проблем , которых вообще не должно появляться при правильной разработке и архитектуре приложения.

Comment: Согласен, плюсую!

Comment: @pavlofff а что предлагаете? провести автору трехдневный мастер класс как по архитектуре андроид приложений? SO по определению сервис вопросов и ответов - автор задает конкретный вопрос - получает конкретный ответ, как справочник.

Comment: @anber Из комментариев к вопросу и контекста известно, для чего автору понадобилось данное действие.  В конце есть конкретный вопрос - "Есть другие варианты?" - другой вариант есть - правильный. Я посчитал, что автор должен его узнать. Что предлагаете вы? Сказать, как сделать, что ему надо, зная, что так делать неправильно, не моя забота - на вопрос я ответил? По вопросу в заголовке предложено три варианта решения. Я подумал несколько раз, прежде чем писать и решил, что надо написать, как надо делать. Вы можете выразить свое отношение репутацией, если считаете, что моему ответу тут не место .

Comment: @pavlofff Тут проблема более глобальная - в каждом втором вопросе авторы спрашивают какую-то локальную фигню, т.к. не понимают корень своей проблемы. Вы предлагаете у каждого клещами вытягивать что ему надо на самом деле? SO не предполагает такой формат.

Comment: Есть правка вопросов, часто можно привести вопрос в соответствие с правильным ответом - тому кто понимает, что на самом деле надо спрашивающему. Хотя по большому счету согласен, 90% вопросов относится к самым основам, отлично описанным в литературе или гуглиться в первой же поисковой строке.

Answer (score 2):

Положить функцию в переменную нельзя, как в C++ к примеру.

Но можно сделать следующее, создать интерфейс

```
private static interface MyInterface {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

И пару объектов которые имплементят этот интерфейс:

```
MyInterface myInterface1 = new MyInterface() {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        //...
    }
};

MyInterface myInterface2 = new MyInterface() {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        //...
    }
};
```

Положить нужный объект в переменную, и потом просто вызвать у него метод `doSomething()`

Comment: А лямбды в андроиде не поддерживаются?

Comment: @VladD андроид переваривает байткод до 7 Java включительно, лямбды вроде с 8, и в теории ее можно подключить при помощи библиотеки retrolambda, но это костыли.

Comment: Не знал, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Java не позволяет записывать функцию в переменную. Для этого используется понятия **функтор**

Вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369460/help-with-understanding-a-function-object-or-functor-in-java), в которой описан хак, который позволяет тебе это делать. Если кратко - тебе нужен допольнительный интерфейс с одним методом, так называемый *функциональный интерфейс*.

Answer (score 0):

Положите переменную название метода и используйте java.lang.reflect.Method

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

 public class ReflectAction {

 public void startAction(String methodName, long arg1) {
         Method method;
         try {
              method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName,long.class);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
              // ...
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
              // ...                
                Log.d("MyLogs", " no Such Method");
            }

         try {
              method.invoke(this, arg1);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {             
            }        
     }

     public void function1(long arg1) {
     }

     public void function2(long agr1) {
     }

     public void function3(long arg3) {
     }   
     }
```

Comment: Опасаюсь за нервы того кто потом будет читать этот код.

Comment: Ну мало ли какая у автора задача. Может он делает какой-нить текстовый квест, делает описания комнат во внешних файлах, и нужно задать вызов произвольного скрипта, когда комната подгрузилась. А для последующих поколений он составит документацию на движок :)